# Focusing an input field in Ionic not working

Tags: cordova, keyboard, focus, ionic-framework

I've been doing my research and it seems that this is not an uncommon issue or question in the Ionic community. I have a simple form with a view inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="registerData.firstName">
...
```

In my controller I then try to focus the field:

```
document.getElementById("firstName").focus();
```

Of course it doesn't work, so as a few posts that I've seen suggests, I have to add the [Ionic Keyboard Plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard) . I do so by running:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard.git
```

And then I apparently have to set this in my `config.xml` as wel:

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false"/>
<feature name="Keyboard">
  <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="IonicKeyboard"/>
</feature>
```

And then apparently everything should work... but it doesn't. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: use autofocus attribute in input tag as
<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="registerData.firstName" autofocus>
...

Comment: Thing is though that I have a whole bunch of inputs that I'm iterating over to see if values have been provided. Then when one hasn't, I'd like to make that particular field focused. So it's not just a matter of setting one field focused on load.

Comment: Have you tried putting the getElementById inside platform ready function. I have just tested a sample app with the below code and it is working fine. $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("firstName").focus();
  })

Answer (score 10):

You could use `autofocus`, but that will work only first time you open page,so try this directive. It works like a charm for me. 
JS:

```
angular.module('app').directive('focusMe',['$timeout',function ($timeout) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      if (attrs.focusMeDisable === "true") {
        return;
      }
      $timeout(function () {
        element[0].focus();
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show(); //open keyboard manually
        }
      }, 350);
    }
  };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="registerData.firstName" focus-me focus-me-disable={{disableFlag}}>
```

Comment: Hi @mudasserajaz when I use your directive. It gives focus to whichever input has the directive regardless of whether it's true or false..?

Comment: hey @DeanGrobler i have updated html. You can control disableFlag from controller now.

Comment: @MudasserAjaz, your solution works fine in my browser but in iOS neither focus in textbox nor open the keyboard. Does it work for you?

Comment: It works for me, but you need to add following to your config.xml: `  <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false"/>`